# Get weird output with char array C++

Tags: c++

Am trying to read data from a file and store it into a char array. Mostly successful but I get a weird output.
The code function looks like this:

```cpp
char* read_answers() {
    string fileName, data;
    char* answer = new char [50];
    ifstream inFile;
    while(!inFile.is_open()){
        //cout<<endl<<"Please enter the name of the answers file: ";
        //cin>>fileName;
        inFile.open("answers.txt");
        if (!inFile.is_open()){
            cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
            if (inFile.eof())
                continue;
        inFile.get(answer[i]);
        cout << i << answer[i] << endl;
        }
        inFile.close();
    cout << answer[0];
    cout << answer[1];
    cout << answer[2];
    return answer;
}
```

The file looks like this:

```
C
A
C
A
B
D
D
```

and the output looks like this:

```
0C
1

2A
3

4C
5

6A
7

8B
9

10D
11

12D
13

14═
C
A
```

To me it looks like it is storing empty data into the array. Is there anyway to skip reading the blank data?

Comment: you can check for blank data as '\n'. Those are `end of lines` in the file

Comment: Related : [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is with END OF LINE characters (`\n`).

Try changing your `for` with this:

```
int i=0;
while (i < 49 && inFile.get(tmp)){
    char tmp;
    inFile.get(tmp);
    if (tmp != '\n'){
        answer[i] = tmp;
        cout << i << answer[i] << endl;
        i++;
    }
}
answer[i] = '\0';
```

The last line guarantees that the string is well represented in memory

Comment: That fixed it thank you so much. I thought it was the eol's but I didn't quite know how to account for those.

Comment: @MilesBanister I'm not completely rigth, i should start in 0 not in 1! I'll fixit now

Comment: @EduardoPascualAseff your proposed solution suffers from the [while (!eof())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/) problem that needs to be avoided. Use `while (i < 49 && inFile.get(tmp))` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You are not taking into account that `inFile.get()` also reads and returns line break characters, which your loop then outputs. That is why there are blank spaces in your output.

There are other mistakes in your code, such as getting stuck in an endless loop if `inFile.open()` fails, and misusing `inFile.eof()`.

Try this instead:

```cpp
char* read_answers() {
    //string fileName;
    //cout << "Please enter the name of the answers file: ";
    //cin >> fileName;
    ifstream inFile("answers.txt");
    if (!inFile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    char* answer = new char [51];
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    while ((i < 50) && inFile.get(ch)) {
        if ((ch != ' ') && (ch != '\r') && (ch != '\n')) {
            cout << i << ch << endl;
            answer[i] = ch;
            ++i;
        }
    }
    answer[i] = '\0';
    inFile.close();
    cout << answer[0];
    cout << answer[1];
    cout << answer[2];
    return answer;
}
```

Alternatively:

```cpp
char* read_answers() {
    //string fileName;
    //cout << "Please enter the name of the answers file: ";
    //cin >> fileName;
    ifstream inFile("answers.txt");
    if (!inFile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Error opening file" << endl;
        return NULL;
    }
    char* answer = new char [51];
    int i = 0;
    while ((i < 50) && (inFile >> answer[i])) {
        cout << i << answer[i] << endl;
        ++i;
        inFile.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    }
    answer[i] = '\0';
    inFile.close();
    cout << answer[0];
    cout << answer[1];
    cout << answer[2];
    return answer;
}
```